# High DPI - Confusing Resolution With DPI

Tags: gnome, display, display-resolution, hdpi

It appears that Gnome confuses dimensions with DPI.

I'm running Ubuntu 19.04 in a VM on a Macbook with 'Retina' display.  I enabled High DPI via setting scale-monitor-framebuffer and x11-randr-fractional-scaling.

Display Settings reveals fractional scales when I run my VM in a large window, but not when I run it in a small window.  When I resize the VM window, **my DPI isn't changing** -- just my total pixel count.  But the moment my pixel count becomes 'too small', Gnome's Display Settings hides fractional scaling.

When I resize my VM window by draggy-droppy, rather than via the Resolution drop-down in Display Settings, Display Settings auto-chooses either 100% or 200% scaling, and hides the fractional values.

- How can I make my preferred 150% scaling available on a High DPI display with smallish dimensions?
- How can I make my preferred 150% scaling available when the display is resized to a size which is not one of the values suggested by Display Settings?
- Is there a way I can "hard-wire" Gnome to use 150% scaling?